# Generate a sequence of repeated characters in R

Tags: r, sequence

Let's say that I have three letters: a,b,c .
How can I get the following sequence:

```
"a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"
```

Comment: `letters[gl(3, 3)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to use the `rep` function to make sequences,
one way is with the `each` to repeat each element in a vector a number of times, and with the `times` argument, that let you repeat the whole vector a number of times.

Check both in usage here

```r
rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), each = 3)
#> [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"
rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), times = 3)
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>